Can i change the behaviour of tab and autocompletion in winedt?
I use WinEdt 11 and would like, that the tab would behave more like for example in Intellij.
When i type \bin i can use tab to complete it to \binom{}{} with my cursor being in the first {}. I would like that after typing something in the first {} and pushing tab my cursor would enter the second argument. Is there a way to do so?

Placeholders (bullets) are used to indicate positions where text is to be typed. Use Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+Shift+Space to jump to the next or previous bullet.

When you input \bin, \binom{}{} will be the first candidate in the suggestions. At this point, pressing the Tab key or Enter key will automatically insert \binom{}{}, and the cursor will be placed inside the first {}. (Note that both {} contain Placeholders (bullets), respectively.)

If the Ctrl+Space shortcut does not work, it may be preempted by another software, such as PowerToys
.

Does this also solve the issue with the second parameter? Please explain better!
